# recuperar o valor da url sem refresh

Tags: php, javascript, htaccess

estou tentando recuperar o valor da `url` pelo `$_GET` com  php, tenho certeza absoluta que é impossivel por não dar refresh, outra coisa como eu passaria o titulo de cada pagina tambem?

**php**

```
<?php
     if (isset($_GET['url'])) :

        $url = addslashes($_GET['url']);
        $sepURL = explode('/', $url);
        print_r($sepURL);

    endif;

    if (isset($_GET[$sepURL[0]])) :
        $lobby = $sepURL[0];
    endif;

    if (isset($lobby)) :
        require_once('lobby.php');
    else :
        require_once('private.php');
    endif;
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ chat.php?url=$1
```

**links**

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="history.pushState('teste','Bem vindo','https://localhost/chat'); return false;">Geral</a></li>

<li><a href="#" onclick="history.pushState('teste','Amanda Caroline','https://localhost/chat/amanda-caroline'); return false;">Amanda Caroline</a></li>
```

ele esta passando os links certinhos, só não estou conseguindo recuperar o valor deles, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma chamada ajax para o servidor

Comment: mais oque eu passo no data do ajax?

Comment: Acho que nada, já que os dados que precisa estão na url

Comment: man não tem um exemplo pra da uma olhada?

Comment: O SOpt está cheio deles é só pesquisar, tem com todo tipo de biblioteca, framework ou com JS puro

Comment: desculpe minha ignorancia, mais oque é isso?

Comment: Isso o que? O "SOpt" é sigla de **S**tack**O**verflow em **p**or**t**ugues

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90622/discussion-between-mayron-and-guilherme-costamilam).

Answer (score 1):

Se você só quer ler o url vc vai precisar de ajax, eu uso diariamente mas nunca tentei oque você quer fazer, porem é possivel, no meu caso eu usaria ajax para nao dar o refresh e o php para pegar o url, vc pode fazer como desejar, o ajax ficaria assim

```
$(function(){
$('.DCSS').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: './func/dcss.func.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('.DCSS').serialize(),
        success: function( data ){
            $('.aside').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

repare que .DCSS é a classe presente na tag  e é tambem o nome do input submit, o .aside é onde a resposta vai vir, seria uma div para exibir o resultado ou qualquer outro lugar, o url é o url do arquivo onde vai ler o url, isso provavelmente vai te ajuadar

```
<form class="DCSS" action="">
        <li><font class="mais">+</font> <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $DCSS ?> Desenvolvimento CSS" name='DCSS'> </li>
    </form>
```

Uma dica, não use require_once a menos que seja necessario, se o arquivo conter algum erro o require_once ou include_once vai parar de executar o arquivo e a pagina vai ficar branca, é melhor usar o include

Comment: velho so que eu tenho um problema com ajax toda vez q uso url amigavel ele duplica a pagina, vou edita essa pergunta

Comment: Como assim duplica a pagina, ele abre outra aba?

Comment: por exemplo, tenho a `<div id="wrapper">conteudo</div>` quando uso ajax e vou fazer url amigavel, toda vez que interajo com uma coisa que usa ajax no site, ele exibe duas vez a div `wrapper`, por isso n gosto de ajax, ja fiz uma pergunta aqui sobre isso, ngm soube o pq isso acontece

Comment: realmente não consigo entender como seu Ajax faz isso, você provavelmente errou em alguma parti da logica dele, mas sem ver o codigo dele ficaria dificil dizer, mas esse codigo que te passei funciona normal, estou usando agora inclusive